# Published .Net Core website not working with Systemd

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, systemd

I'm trying to deploy an ASP .Net Core app to my webserver, but when I try running the app with a Systemd service, I get http 500 errors in the browser, however if I run the app manually, everything works as expected. When the service is started it tells me the app is running like it should and there are no errors. There is no indication that it isn't working right.
The app should go to localhost:5000 and is then passed through a reverse proxy on Nginx to the internet. That part works fine.
The service code is below, maybe there is an error in it?

```
[Unit]
Description=bazinga.tech-website

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/bazinga-db/bazinga/CSharpWebsite.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=bazinga-website
User=bazinga
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am using an example from [Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction#monitoring-our-application) on deploying to a Linux server.
The command I would use to run manually is:

```
dotnet CSharpWebsite.dll
```

Any idea why it may not work? I can provide some screenshots if requested. This is the first time I've used Systemd to start a program manually, so any help is appreciated.

bazinga = my name for obscurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out I was missing the WorkingDirectory line in the service file. Must have deleted it by mistake when editing the Microsoft example.

Comment: Here's the link to the full thread, found this on the internet: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/solved-systemd-service-not-working-right/112660/10